# How to draw two time series in one graph using "ts.plot"

Tags: r, plot, time-series

Im an R beginner, and spent almost two days to figure out how one can draw two time-series inside one graph using "ts.plot". This should be a very simple task, but for some reason there was always something wrong.

My Dataset looks like this:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbDb.png)

Comment: Are you answering your own question here? If so, StackOverflow encourages this, but please make the question a question, then answer your own question in the answers section. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I followed your advice, and reworked it. Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and there are several ways to accomplish the task.

This is the most straightworward way: assign "variable_1" to "x" and "variable_2" to "y". Then use "ts.plot" to plot the graph:

```
x <- usa$central_bank_assets_gdp_percent
y <- usa$domestic_credit_private_sector_gdp
ts.plot(ts(x), ts(y), col=1:2)
```

Defining the location of the master dataset first, and then including the real variable names in the code:

```
attach(usa)
ts.plot(ts(central_bank_assets_gdp_percent), ts(domestic_credit_private_sector_gdp), col=1:2)
detach(usa)
```

Using the "$" sign as an alternative to specifying the location of the data:

```
ts.plot(ts(usa$central_bank_assets_gdp_percent), ts(usa$domestic_credit_private_sector_gdp), col=1:2)
```

Using "data.frame()" one can include the variables:

```
ts.plot(data.frame(usa$central_bank_assets_gdp_percent, usa$financial_system_deposits_gdp_percent), col=1:2)
```

This is the way specified in the help: Using "ts.plot(..., gpars = list())". In this case "..." are the variables, and all other functions go in the "gpars=list()":

```
ts.plot(ts(usa$central_bank_assets_gdp_percent), ts(usa$financial_system_deposits_gdp_percent), gpars = list(col=1:2))
```

Comment: I modified your code. `d <- data.frame(country=rep("USA",7), 
                time=1961:1967,
                bank_deposits_gdp_percent=c(57.39, 58.54, 60.55, 61.37, 61.79, 60.43, 61.35),
                central_bank_assets_gdp_percent=c(5.11, 5.06, 5.18, 5.27, 5.34, 5.35, 5.55),
                cpi_2005=c(13.71, 13.87, 14.05, 14.23, 14.46, 14.89, 15.30))
d2 <- ts(start=1961, d[d$country=="USA", 3:4])
ts.plot(d2, col=c(2, 4), lty=c(3, 1), lwd=2)`